# Using a bluetooth audio device in another computer

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, homegroup

Because my PC doesn't have bluetooth. I want to use my laptop as some sort of a station for my audio device. So that if say I have compuer A and I want to hear from some device A the audio that should be coming from computer A. I connect device A to computer B and still hear the sound that should be coming from compuer A.

Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: You're saying that you want to link the device to computer B and have the audio output on computer A?  Have you considered just buying a Bluetooth USB dongle for computer A?  They're inexpensive and that would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Bluetooth standard does not talk about doing anything even close to what you describe.  You are better off just adding Bluetooth capabilities to your device.

Comment: @Ramhound He is asking how he can play audio from computer A to computer B and hear it on a device connected to his laptop via bluetooth, because computer A does not have bluetooth capability.

Comment: I understand what the author wants to do.

Answer (score 3):

Just to reiterate your situation:
[image: Your layout]

You want to drive a bluetooth device running through your laptop.

To achieve this you will need to have both of the computers running on the same network, and you will also need a program called [Voicemeeter Banana](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) running on your PC and [VBAN Receptor](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/vban.htm) installed on your laptop.  VBAN allows you to stream audio between two computers over the network.

**Note:** When installing Voicemeeter make sure you run the setup as admin!! Doing otherwise can result in a broken install.

After installing all the components on each computer follow these steps:

1. On Computer A press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd> and type in `mmsys.cpl`, press enter.  On the Playback tab of the window that pops up, find `Voicemeeter Input`, right click it and select Set as Default Device. 
   [image: Setting the default device]
2. On Computer A, open Voicemeeter Banana and click the button in the picture that says B1 on Strip 4 (it will turn green)
   [image]
   Now, in the top right of the window click the VBAN button.
   [image]
   Under the section that says Outgoing Streams change the settings of the first stream to be:

   - "On"
   - Source: BUS B1
   - Stream Name: Doesn't matter
   - IP Address To: Your Laptop's IP Address
   - Port: 6980
   - SamplerRate: 48000 Hz
   - Ch: 2
   - Format: PCM 16 bits
   - Net Quality: Optimal

[image: VBAN Config]
Keep Voicemeeter and VBAN open on Computer A.

3. Now move to Computer B and open VBAN Receptor (which you should've installed).  At the bottom of the window click the button that says `A1` and select your bluetooth device that you wish to play to (headset, speakers, etc)

[image: VBAN Receptor]

Jump back over to Computer A for a moment and click the button in the top left of the VBAN Config window that says `VBAN is off` to start streaming.  It will turn blue and change to `VBAN is on`.  In the section that says Outgoing Streams where we put our stream configuration you should see a little green box appear next to the IP address when you are successfully streaming.
[image: Streaming]

Going back to Computer B, in the VBAN Receptor window **left** click on the area that says "Stream Name" and "IP Address From".  A box will appear with the stream name we set on Computer A.  Click it and if you play some audio on Computer A you should be able to hear it on your Bluetooth device through Computer B.

Voicemeeter is a powerful program.  I would recommend configuring it further to better suit your needs and give you more control by [reading the docs](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/VoicemeeterBanana_UserManual.pdf)

Comment: For some reasom I have the green light but when I click on stream name in VBAN, nothing comes up. Also I have used the IPv4 of my laptop, am I doing anything wrong? @Jesse Wallace

Comment: @Ariel Go on Computer A and press Windows+R type in `cmd` and press Enter.  Now in the command prompt that appears type in `ping IP ADDRESS` replacing <IP ADDRESS> with the IP of Computer B.  Press enter and if you see something like `Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=Xms TTL=128` then you can communicate with your laptop.  If not then you need to check your network configuration.  If you can then you need to try letting VBAN through the firewall (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) and disabling antivirus.

Comment: Thx! Seems to be working now. Just very bad quality. Maybe because the sound is moving in my local network? Can I do anything to make it better? It usually shows the overload and underrun with red color

Comment: @Ariel Try either connecting both computers directly to the router, or directly to each other (via ethernet cord) the IP addresses will change so you need to find and update those.  Also before you do that try changing the stream settings on Computer A.  Change the SamplerRate to 44100 Hz and step the NetQuality down until you see a change.

Comment: in case of frequent cut in the sound (frequent overload and underrun error) , slow down the Network Quality on receiver. (set it to slow or very slow).

Comment: @user258609 You can also lower the SamplerRate of the stream to 44100 Hz for a slight performance bump